# What are validation options for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

What are my validation options with .net mvc?

Do any of them have a nice validation summary like webforms did?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a MVC html validation summary,see this blog

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/08/29/Form-validation-with-ASPNET-MVC-preview-5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

xVal is the best one. We implemented in three web applications and we will use it in many more in the future(until we find a better one than this). Check the details of xVal here

http://blog.codeville.net/2009/01/10/xval-a-validation-framework-for-aspnet-mvc/