# Should I use MS Validation Application Block in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I know that the [MS Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309509.aspx) *can* be [used with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234006/what-are-validation-options-for-asp-net-mvc) but I'm not sure if I **should**. It looks like it hasn't been updated since 2007 - which is probably fine - I'm just being extra cautious before adopting something new into my app that i haven't used before.

Is there any reason not to - or what does it do for me that is so great - or is there somethin upcoming I should wait for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fine to use. There are some MVC projects that use it like [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/).

The Validation Application Block got updates in 4.1 as well. The link you have is to an older version. Find out more about 4.1 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140088.aspx

Comment: thats good enough for me! i'll check out xVal. i assume they had time to do more homework than I did. glad you pointed out the new version too!